# "No Code Behind File"

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have been working on c# Gui for about a week without problem, all of a sudden when I added a label control I tried to access its events and saw the error "This document item has no code behind file. Add code behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers"

This is odd since the gui/methods still runs fine but it is making it very difficult to progress...any ideas? Did a file get deleted etc? Can provide more info on request, thanks for the help!

(couldn't add screen shot unfortunately yet but error is displayed in properties window/event tab)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error"This document item has no code behind file. Add code behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers" in my first C++ Helloworld project when I try to add a even handler for one button I added in the MainPage.xaml.

I solved the problem by restart Visual Studio 2015 and recreate a new project, then  I add a even handler for the button successfully.

It's my experience and just be posted here that maybe you can use it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, too.  In my project, most UserControls were fine, but there was one group that showed the "no code-behind" message instead of properties.  The .cs files did exist, though.  In the Solution Explorer tree, the xaml files all had xaml.cs files.  I checked the csproj file, and all the xaml.cs files were tagged as `<DependentUpon>` the correct matching xaml file.

I was able to fix this by closing the solution, then deleting the csproj.vspscc (Source Control Project Metadata) file for the project.  When I reopened the solution, that metadata file was rebuilt and the Properties were available in Visual Studio again.